Vectorize __float128 dot product with SIMD/AVX
If I have in C++11 (on Linux, with gcc on Intel Xeon) two __float128* arrays A and B (fixed size, fits entirely in the cache), do you know of/can provide a code that makes the __float128 dot product of those arrays (i.e. the sum of their element-wise product) using SIMD/AVX acceleration where possible.
Unfortunately MKL (and no efficient BLAS library afaik) supports __float128, so this acceleration would reduce somewhat the massive __float128 slowdown versus double to a point where we really can use it.
There are numerical stability reasons to go for __float128 in our case, so less than that is not an option unfortunately.

10x slower then double seems very optimistic (in case of lack of hardware support). I cannot imagine how to code it with just 10 double operation. -- Try to avoid 128-bit float. Use numerics not to lose too much precision (and with 128 and bad numerics.. it help just a little)

Thanks for the help! We  do our best to solve the problem upstream but there are always cases that won't be improvable! I would assume some AVX could help do all the double operations at the same time for several quad ops at the same time? Unfortunately quality BLAS libraries mostly stop existing at that precision.

AVX may help (and other optimization) if your code has more code. For now there is just an addition, so no way to parallelize or mix instructions. -- My comments about numerics was not about using BLAS et al., but to order flow of operation not to have to use 128-bit. Or check videocard libraries. Note: lack of good numerical libraries is also a hints about few people really need them, so they will not implement it.

Have you actually profiled your current code base and verified this is your actual bottleneck in your code? Often the performance is limited by memory bandwidth (cache misses) and/or missed branch predictions. Make sure you are not measuring the perfomance of std::cout.  And do you even have optimizations enabled?  A compiler may see right through such a "simple loop" and add a constant to finalval (maybe not with your expected precission though)

If this is your real code then it can be trivially replaced with finalval  = val * 729 * 2100 * 64, if it's not your code then we need a [mre]

The example snippet is of course not what we actually do... It does show a minimal example of the actual issue we are facing though.

@Halbux Re "a sum, which I read is supposed to be only 10x slower than in double precision" This seems unlikely. A correctly implemented double-double addition requires 20 double-precision operations, and that generally provides lower precision than __float128 addition.

@njuffa : ok, makes sense. But are there any implementations that allow to multiply or sum a bunch of __float128 at the same time with AVX256/512? I have tons of them that can be computed in one go.

@Halbux I would suggest updating the question with a representative example of actual usage. The only thing we know for now is that the example currently provided is not representative. By "at the same time" do you mean specifically computation in multiple SIMD lanes (-> vectorization), or are you generally referring to ILP (instruction level parallelism)? The latter should already happen automatically: parts of the emulation sequences for __float128 operations naturally overlap in execution on out-of-order processors.

Good point @njuffa . Question is updated in a way that goes to the point of our actual problem.

@Halbux You might want to add information about the typical length of the vectors whose dot product is being computed. BLAS1 operations like ?DOT are generally considered to be constrained by memory bandwidth, and with current large disparities between computational throughput and memory throughput that might even extend to computations with higher computational density forced by use of __float128 if the vectors are long enough.

people have reported that it's ~10-20 times slower, which is as expected. SIMD is for parallel execution, so it's very difficult to quickly propagate carry to the higher significant parts which is done in serial. Therefore you can't make it faster for standard IEEE-754 formats. For higher precision you should use the double-double arithmetic format instead which is more suitable for parallelization

In fact double-double arithmetic is very common on PowerPC. The elements are calculated separately so no need to do the carry. This technique is also used in CUDA in the past for getting higher precision when double support wasn't available, and you know CUDA is just as "vectorized" as SIMD

Should you need the exponent range of __float128, you can convert a double-double arithmetic library to using double-__float80. __float80 on x86_64 has the same 15bit exponent range as __float128, and it may be faster because __float80 uses hardware acceleration. double-__float80 would be equivalent to using a 128bit mantissa compared to __float128 112bit mantissa.
As for AVX/SIMD, you can try modifying dd_real or qd_real from QD to use AVX intrinsics, yielding roughly 104 and 208 mantissa bits respectively.
